# How to change the data type of a CSV when INSERTING the data into SQL server via Python?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I'm pulling data from a feed and saving it as a .csv file, which is then being inserted into SQL server.

However, the column "datetime" is by default, set as nvarchar(50).

How can I make it so that this datetime column converts to the datatype datetime BEFORE inserting it into the SQL table?

Also, how can I substring the datetime column into 2 separate columns such as column: date and column: time before inserting into the table?

The substring and left functions that I want to use are:
SUBSTRING(datetime,12,5) as 'time'
LEFT(datetime,10) as 'date'

```
columns = ['Datetime', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 
        'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume']


df_data = df[columns]
records = df_data.values.tolist()



    
sql_insert = '''
    INSERT INTO Live_Ticker
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
'''
```

Comment: What code are you using to insert the records? Are you able to provide the table schema?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If the datatype of the column you are inserting in is an `nvarchar(50)`, why do you need to cast to a `datetime`? Why isn't the column a `datetime` to begin with? I think you are asking how to change the format of the csv value. From your code it looks like you're reading the csv in python, surely you can do whatever you want with the data there. But if you have any control over the database, you'll do yourself a favor to choose the correct datatype. An `nvarchar(50)` is not the correct datatype if you want it to store `datetime` data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you add the date and time columns, just cast the value to the intended type:

```
DECLARE @datetime datetime = ?;
sql_insert = '''
INSERT INTO Live_Ticker ("date", "time","Open","High","Low","Close","Adj Close","Volume") 
VALUES (cast(@datetime As date), cast(@datetime as time) ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

'''